# by using jsoup get xml data

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to `parse xml` data by using `jsoup`. I put each data into `array list`. It is already working, however, when I get the `data`, each `data` is going into same line. 
For example, the data I get from is

```
RESULT
    ITEM
    R1
      B DESC =""
        B1
      C DESC =""
        CR1
           C1
        CR2
           C1
        CR3
           C1
```

And my java code is

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();            
Elements elements = document.select("ITEM");
for (Element element : elements) {
   medicationBasic = new MedicationBasic();
   medicationBasic.setProductName(element.select("B1").text());
   medicationOrigin = new MedicationOrigin();
   medicationOrigin.setMedOrigin(element.select("C1").text());
   list.add(medicationBasic);
   list.add(medicationOrigin);
   response = new ResponseList(Result.SUCCESS, (ArrayList) list);
```

what I get is:

```
{
productName:"B1",
medOrigin:"C1(from CR1) C1(from CR2) C1(from CR3)"
}
```

what is expected:

```
{
productName:"B1",
medOrigin:"C1(from CR1)"
}

{
productName:"B1",
medOrigin:"C1(from CR2)"
}

{
productName:"B1",
medOrigin:"C1(from CR3)"
}
```

what is wrong with my code?? Please help me on this...

Comment: Be more specific: post actual xml data and actual (unexpected) output.

Comment: that xml name is actual thing that I am trying to get from

Comment: Is this resolved?

Comment: `I only posted basic logic and concept that what I am doing. It is pretty clear. Whoever down voted this, that says you just don't know what to do.` No, that is not what downvotes indicate (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Simply by using Strings instead of your missing classes and by posting similar XML as I used in my answer you could have produced a more generalized problem, that still reproduces your issue but has no compile-time errors. Have another look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

`element.select("C1")` selects all C1 elements inside the ITEM (returns `Elements`) and `text()` returns the [combined text](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#text--):

> public String text() Get the combined text of all the matched
>   elements.

**Fix**
Iterate over the C1 elements and add key-value pairs.

**Example Code**

```
String xmlString = "<RESULT>\r\n" + 
        "    <ITEM>\r\n" + 
        "       <R1>\r\n" + 
        "           <B DESC =\"\">\r\n" + 
        "               <B1>B1<B1>\r\n" + 
        "           </B>\r\n" + 
        "           <C DESC =\"\">\r\n" + 
        "               <CR1>\r\n" + 
        "                   <C1>C1(from CR1)</C1>\r\n" + 
        "               </CR1>\r\n" + 
        "               <CR2>\r\n" + 
        "                   <C1>C1(from CR2)</C1>\r\n" + 
        "               </CR2>\r\n" + 
        "               <CR3>\r\n" + 
        "                   <C1>C1(from CR3)</C1>\r\n" + 
        "               </CR3>\r\n" + 
        "           </C>\r\n" + 
        "       </R1>\r\n" + 
        "   </ITEM>\r\n" + 
        "</RESULT>";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(xmlString);

List<SimpleEntry<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

Elements elements = document.select("ITEM");
for (Element element : elements) {
    String medicationBasic = element.select("B1").text();
    element.select("C1").forEach(c1Element -> {
        String medicationOrigin = c1Element.text();
        list.add(new SimpleEntry<String, String>(medicationBasic, medicationOrigin));

    });
}

System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**

```
[B1 =C1(from CR1), B1 =C1(from CR2), B1 =C1(from CR3)]
```

Comment: thank you for reply...sorry I didn't understand you. Where I am getting xml is a website...not from a text...so, I can't really put that xml into String right?

Comment: StringBuilder queryUrl = new StringBuilder();
        queryUrl.append("http://drug.mfds.go.kr/admin/openapi/detailSearch.do?bc=");
queryUrl.append(medicationCode);

Comment: That is why I previously asked for the actual xml. Just use your Document as before, the relevant part is the handling of the C1 elements, as described in my answer.

Comment: On a side note: the fact, that you are not providing the information to reproduce your issue (had to write my own xml; without a medication code url is still incomplete; class definition are missing, so posted code does not even compile) is probably the reason for the downvotes of the question. You might want to fix these issues and update your question.

Comment: I truly believe this is not the place you ask for full solution code. I only posted basic logic and concept that what I am doing. It is pretty clear. Whoever down voted this, that says you just don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I solved my problem by doing as below:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();            
Elements bElement = document.select("B DESC");
Elements cElement = document.select("C DESC>*");
for (Element bElement : elements) {
   medicationBasic = new MedicationBasic();
   medicationBasic.setProductName(element.select("B1").text());
   list.add(medicationBasic);
}
for (Element cElement : elements) {
   medicationOrigin = new MedicationOrigin();
   medicationOrigin.setMedOrigin(element.select("C1").text());
   list.add(medicationOrigin);
}
response = new ResponseList(Result.SUCCESS, (ArrayList) list);
```

I got the result as what I expected